# WCF Web service is throwing EndPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, wcf-endpoint

I am trying to configure a WCF service to support duplex communication to a client service and since I switched to WSDualHttpBinding I now get this on the service in IIS

> There was no endpoint listening at http://exampple.com/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/06be1668-e09f-441c-9fc9-999e4922d4a8/1002945c-979b-484e-a2c5-fa3470b6706d that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. The inner exception is null and basically the service on the server is hosted in IIS then I have a self hosted service on the client machine that connects to the server and a client application that connects to the self hosted service. The wsDualHttpbinding is from the server to the self hosted service and the self hosted service exposes a named pipe for the client application to communicate with.

Here is the Web.config from the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <remove scheme="http" />
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsDualHttp_EcuWebBinding" />
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EcuWebServiceBehavior" name="EcuWeb.Service.EcuWebService">
        <endpoint address="/EcuWebService.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsDualHttp_EcuWebBinding" name="WsDualHttp_EcuWeb" contract="EcuWeb.Service.IEcuWebService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EcuWebServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="EcuWebService.svc" service="EcuWeb.Service.EcuWebService" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is the App.config from my host application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51334/EcuWebService.svc/EcuWebService.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsDualHttp_EcuWeb" contract="EcuWebService.IEcuWebService" name="WsDualHttp_EcuWeb">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="myusername@domain.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="NetNamedPipeBehavior_EcuService">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipedBinding_EcuService" />
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WsDualHttp_EcuWeb" />
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBehavior_EcuService"
                name="Ecu.Services.EcuService">
                <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/EcuNamedPipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipedBinding_EcuService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEcuService" contract="Ecu.Services.IEcuService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And finally the App.config from the client test application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEcuService" />
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/EcuNamedPipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEcuService" contract="EcuServiceClient.IEcuService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEcuService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I see your point to save space posting on an external pastebin but months will pass and external resource posted code can disappear what will make your question (and possible answer) pointless.

Comment: I tried putting it in code tags first and it only showed the first line instead of the whole config. That is the only reason i resorted to pastebin. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Use 4 spaces intend to format code, very simple :)

Comment: From the exception: "See InnerException, if present, for more details." Was there an inner exception by chance?

Comment: So do you host in IIS or self-host in an application?

Comment: I see wsDualHttpBinding only in Service's config, and netNamedPipeBinding in clients' config,

Comment: I have updated my post that answers your questions. Basically the client and server both talk to a service that is client side. That is where the middle config comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten this fixed thanks to another post on SO that pointed me to this article about WCF Duplex services. [Duplex Article](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx)

Once I switched over to net.tcp and got everything setup to use it the duplex communication worked no problem.